# Javascript Display the first letter of every array element only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm tying to display the first letter of every array element only once along with the main element title. I have listed the example below where you can see the list along with it's respected first letter. I want the list to appear as it is, but don't want to get their first letter repeated.
https://jsfiddle.net/z42u1d9o/

My code:

```
var cars = ["Brown", "Blue", "Bingo", "Vietnam", "America", "India", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
cars = cars.sort();
return cars.map(item => {
    var firstLetter = item.split('')[0];
  text += item + '-' +firstLetter + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
})
```

Comment: Please could you mention, what problem are you facing? what is expected output?

Comment: It's nice, but your text does not include a problem, nor an actual question. I could now start guessing what the problem is, but why should i? Do you want each first letter to only appear once, as in, e.g. no multiple "A"?

Comment: I have asked in the very first sentence that I want to display the first letter only once, so how to avoid displaying it every time

Comment: I have made it more clear in the text now.

Comment: So you want it to be ["Brown-B", "Blue", "Bingo"] for the first three items?

Comment: Yes correct @Ric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an object to store every added letter and to check against while looping through the array.

```js
var cars = ["Brown", "Blue", "Bingo", "Vietnam", "America", "India", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"],
    text = "",
    alreadyAdded = {},
    firstLetter = "";
  
  cars.sort();

  for (car of cars) {
     firstLetter = car[0];
     
     if (alreadyAdded[firstLetter]) {
        text += car;
     } else {
        alreadyAdded[firstLetter] = true;
        text += car + "-" + firstLetter;
     }

     text += " ";
  }


console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach -

```js
let result = ["Brown", "Blue", "Bingo", "Vietnam", "America", "India", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"].sort().map((d, i, a) => (i == 0 || d[0] != a[i-1][0]) ? d + '-' + d[0] : d)


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Ah! Without Output it becomes difficult what is wanted. Done the edit @ShoebMirza. Does it look good now?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be able to use filter with a filter function.

The code would become something like this

```js
var cars = ["Brown", "Blue", "Bingo", "Vietnam", "America", "India", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
cars = cars.sort();
var firstLetters = cars.map(item=>item.split('')[0]).filter((x,y,z)=>z.indexOf(x) === y);

firstLetters.map(item => {
 text += item + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to have the list display as it is and besides that I want it's first letter but if it has repeated before it should not get repeat again

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have a List in the end, with the Letters as section headers. So I'd suggest using an object approach.

```
function getList(){
  let cars = ["Brown", "Blue", "Bingo", "Vietnam", "America", "India", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
  let list = {};
  cars.sort();
  cars.forEach((car) => {
    let section = car.charAt(0);
    if (list[section] == null){
      list[section] = [];
    }
    list[section].push(car);
  });
  return list;
}
```

This will create a simple object with the section headers and an array.

```
{ A: [ 'America', 'Audi' ],
  B: [ 'Bingo', 'Blue', 'Brown' ],
  F: [ 'Fiat', 'Ford' ],
  I: [ 'India' ],
  S: [ 'Saab' ],
  V: [ 'Vietnam', 'Volvo' ] }
```